# Monodroid binding change variable name

Tags: binding, xamarin.android, bugsense

I try to bind BugSense 3.0.5 to MonoDroid. I create a new Java Binding Library project, add the bugsense3.0.5.jar to the Jars-folder. I build it, and get the following error:

'Crash': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

```
The auto generate code:
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/bugsense/trace/models/Crash", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public partial class Crash : global::Java.Lang.Object, global::Java.IO.ISerializable {


        [Register ("CRASH")]
        public const int Crash = (int) 1;
```

So I need to rename the global variable "Crash" in the Metadata.xml- but how do I do that?

I have try:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.bugsense.trace.models']/class[@name='Crash']/field[@name='Crash']" name="managedName">mCrash</attr>
```

But it fails: matched no nodes

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it renaming the class instead

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.bugsense.trace.models']/class[@name='Crash']]" name="managedName">Crashed</attr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always look for original fields name in java. 
As i know it is lowerCamelCase. And it is probably hidden into setter/getter so you should search for `/method[@name='getCrash']`